# Navigation bar (iphone)

Tags: iphone

I have created email functionality view in which everything is working fine, but the color of a navigation bar item is not changing like other views. I have used below code for navigation color but 1 navigation bar button item is left with default color. How do I change it?

```
controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you create the bar button item yourself? If so, you can change its background color by making sure it's a "custom view" type button item:

```
// Assuming you have some predetermined width w and height h
UIView *backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] 
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, w, h)] autorelease];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIBarButtonItem *myItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithCustomView:backgroundView] autorelease];
```

Then you can change the background color at a future date by setting the `backgroundColor` property on the bar button item's `customView`:

```
myItem.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: {
 MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 NSMutableArray *messgeToField = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 NSString *str= @"aedproject@psu.com";
 [messgeToField addObject:str];
 [controller setToRecipients:messgeToField];
 [controller setSubject:@"Feedback"];
 [controller setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
 controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
 [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
 [controller release];
 [messgeToField release];
}

Comment: i have used this code for email functionality. i am not creating any navigation bar or bar button item not from a nib 2. i have 2 bar buttons item.
controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
this code only changes the color of 1 bar button item. tell me any solution 4 ds

Comment: @Harita: what button isn't changing? If it's the Send button in MFMailComposeViewController, this is desired behavior and I'm not sure there's a way around it. The docs (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) even say that the mail composition interface itself shouldn't be changed.

Comment: In that case there's not much I can say. The Send button isn't really supposed to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

How about use this?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

of course on your viewDidLoad